# Why is it matching two Properties - regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex where I want to get Properties which contains %%text%%, but my regex is capturing more than that

My regex: `(<Properties>).+?%%.+?%%.+?(<\/Properties>)`

It maches:

```
"<Properties>
<Property>TEXT</Property>
</Properties>
<Properties>
<Property >%%TEXT%%</Property>
</Properties>"
```

But I want him to match only:

```
"<Properties>
<Property >%%TEXT%%</Property>
</Properties>"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can't parse [X]HTML with regex. Because HTML can't be parsed by regex
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: No worries, it's a string

Comment: You also have an invalid tag `</Property` is that intentional? Is there new lines in your string?

Comment: There are no new lines

Comment: Could you not just use `<Properties><Property>%%.*%%<\/Property><\/Properties>` ? Assuming you have only one "property" in each "properties"? [Test here](https://regex101.com/r/cUy5YP/2)

Comment: I can have many many property tags inside Properties

Comment: I have big XML String, where in some Properties I have variables with %%something%%, and I need to find all Properties who containains it and loop them trough and replace %%something%% with actual value.

I can take all properties, and loop them trough and find this whom has this variable, but that ir overhead to my server

Comment: How about using [XPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript) instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [tempered greedy token](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed) instead of `.`:

```
<Properties>(?:(?!<\/Properties>)[^])*%%(.+?)%%(?:(?!<\/Properties>)[^])*<\/Properties>
```

This part `(?:(?!<\/Properties>)[^])` makes sure we haven't `</properties>` before the wanted text.

`[^]` stands for any character including newlines.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hN1yId/3)

Comment: Take a look: https://regex101.com/r/hN1yId/4 It still has issues :(

Comment: @JānisSeržants: It had, I've done a correction, revisit the link provided in demo.

Comment: I was learning from w3schools (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) about regex, but now I see there aren't full list of regex options, where can I read more about for example `?:` ?

Comment: @JānisSeržants https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html

Comment: @JānisSeržants: [Tempered greedy token](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed)

Answer (score 1):

Let's break down the regex vs the actual match so you can see why it matches:

```regex
(<Properties>).+?%%.+?%%.+?(<\/Properties>)
```

- `(<Properties>)` matches the first `<Properties>`.
- `.+?` matches one or more characters until it encounters `%%`, thus matching `<Property>TEXT</Property><Properties><Property >`.
- `%%` matches `%%`.
- `.+?` matches one or more characters until it encounters `%%`, thus matching `TEXT`.
- `%%` matches `%%`.
- `.+?` matches one or more characters until it encounters `</Properties>` thus matching `</Property`.
- `(<\/Properties>)` matches `</Properties>`.

Instead you want to make your regex more explicit:

```regex
(?:[^<%]|%(?!%)|<(?!\/Properties>))
```

The above will match **one** character that is not `<` or `%`, if it is one of those two it will only match `%` if not followed by another `%` and it will only match `<` if not followed by `/Properties>`. This should be used as replacement for your `.`. Resulting in:

```regex
(<Properties>)(?:[^<%]|%(?!%)|<(?!\/Properties>))+%%(?:[^<%]|%(?!%)|<(?!\/Properties>))+%%(?:[^<%]|%(?!%)|<(?!\/Properties>))+(<\/Properties>)
```

Since the regex is more explicit I can remove the lazy `?` quantifier modifier safely.